# How to redefine baseurl by sections?

Tags: hyperref, urls

In writing my resume, I have found `\hypersetup{baseurl=`*`url`*`}` to be quite handy. For example, I could just define my GitHub homepage as the base URL and write `\url{helloworld}` to have it automatically point to the project page while showing only the project name on paper. On the other hand, I could also define the DOI homepage as the base URL and write `##.####/xxxxxx` and have a valid DOI link. The problem is I can't do both in one document.

According to the `hyperref` package documentation:

> \hyperbaseurl{URL}
>   A base URL is established, which is prepended to other specified URLs, to make
>   it easier to write portable documents.

From the description, it seems I just have to use this user macro, but it didn't work.

How do I achieve what I want without resorting to hacks like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216134/is-it-possible-to-redefine-url-in-such-a-way-that-it-works-without-or-with-http)? Am I just misunderstanding something and using the macro wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base URL is a global property of the PDF file and is written in the document's catalog object. Therefore, it cannot be changed locally.

There are packages like [`doi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/doi) or [`doipubmed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/doipubmed) that provide a `\doi` macro.