# Set alternative URL link address

Tags: hyperref

I want to put a "short" URL (without http://) in my document: something like `\url{google.com}`. But if I do that, the link does not work (it tries to link locally, and does not recognize it as a web address).

I also tried `\href{http://google.com}{google.com}`, which links correctly, but shows "google.com" in standard font instead of the nice URL monospaced font. I could do `\href{http://google.com}{\texttt{google.com}}` to get the monospaced font, but other things like URL wrapping don't work.

Is there some way that I can have the link work, and have the URL formatted nicely?

Also, apologies if this has already been asked. It seems like it must have been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: `\href{http...}{hello}`  makes the link text hello link to http... see hyperref manual

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to avoid the “http:” part in `hyperref`'s `\url`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139921/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Yes, thank you Werner, that's just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

The `\nolinkurl` command can be used to format a URL without creating a link. This can be combined with `\href` to get the desired effect:

```
\href{http://google.com}{\nolinkurl{google.com}}
```

This [duplicate issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139921/how-to-avoid-the-http-part-in-hyperrefs-url) shows the specific case when only the "http://" has been omitted (thanks @Werner for finding this).